# How to omit curly braces when using cookiecutter?

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I'm building a cookiecutter template in Python, something fairly simple for now, that looks like this:

```
├── {{ cookiecutter.project_name }}
│    └── test.py
│
└── cookiecutter.json
```

When I run the cookiecutter command on the command line and point it to this template, it correctly asks me for the `project_name` input. However, the problem is that in my `test.py` script, there is a print statement with double curly braces as well, so in the end, the cookiecutter command fails, with the following error:

```
  File "./test.py", line 73, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'
  File "./test.py", line 73
    print(('{{"RequestId":"{0}", '
```

Is there a way to tell cookiecutter to omit certain curly braces?

Comment: Apparently the way you get double curly braces into your template is `{{ '{{' }}` - I don't have cookiecutter installed to actually test this.

Comment: @jasonharper not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Put that string at the point where the file is supposed to contain `{{`.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, that worked! If you post your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

From cookiecutter's [Troubleshooting docs](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html) (or from the underlying [Jinja Templating docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping)), to prevent cookiecutter from incorrectly parsing braces `{` or `{{` from the template:

> Make sure you escape things properly, like this:
>
> ```
> {{ "{{" }}
> ```
>
> Or this:
>
> ```
> {{ {{ url_for('home') }} }}
> ```
>
> See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping for more info.

If the template is like this:

```
marker = '{{'
print('{{RequestId:{0}, ')
print('The value should be in braces {{{cookiecutter.value}}}')
```

The braces need to be escaped like this:

```
marker = '{{ "{{" }}'
print('{{ "{{" }}RequestId:{0}, ')
print('The value should in braces {{ "{" }}{{cookiecutter.value}}{{ "}" }}')
```

So that it generates properly:

```
$ cat template/\{\{\ cookiecutter.project_name\ \}\}/test.py
marker = '{{ "{{" }}'
print('{{ "{{" }}RequestId:{0}, ')
print('The value should in braces {{ "{" }}{{cookiecutter.value}}{{ "}" }}')

$ cookiecutter template
project_name [myproject]: 
value [the_value]: 123456

$ cat myproject/test.py
marker = '{{'
print('{{RequestId:{0}, ')
print('The value should in braces {123456}')
```

Another option is, rather than escaping each `{` in test.py, you can just tell cookiecutter to skip the *entire* test.py file by adding it to the [Copy without Render](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/copy_without_render.html) list (available from cookiecutter 1.1+):

> To avoid rendering directories and files of a cookiecutter, the *_copy_without_render* key can be used in the *cookiecutter.json*.
>
> ```
> {
>    "project_slug": "sample",
>    "_copy_without_render": [
>        "*.html",
>        "*not_rendered_dir",
>        "rendered_dir/not_rendered_file.ini"
>    ]
> }
> ```

From the original example, in case you are only templating the folder name and leaving everything in test.py untouched, then cookiecutter.json should be:

```
{
    "project_name": "myproject",

    "_copy_without_render": [
        "test.py"
    ]
}
```